# Redirecting a .txt file to /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: unix

Is it possible to direct a text file to /etc/resolv.conf. I tried:

```
sudo
DNSinfo.txt > /etc/resolv.conf
```

so far I'm getting an error of

```
namespace: unknown
```

and its not writing to the file.

Comment: With your command `DNSinfo.txt > /etc/resolv.conf` you are trying to execute `DNSinfo.txt` and redirect its output to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cat yourfile.txt >> target_file
```

">>" here means append its content to the end of target file. Don't mistake it to ">", which will overwrite the target file except you mean it

Answer (score 1):

The below should work . If you don't have permission try as sudo

```
 cat DNSinfo.txt >> /etc/resolv.conf
```